# Woocommerce send BCC email with snippet

Tags: woocommerce

This code below will send a BCC:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'firefog_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);
function firefog_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'new_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: NAME <name@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

But how can i apply the below code to the BCC email?

```
<script type="application/json+trustpilot">
    {
        "recipientName": "Dynamic code...",
        "recipientEmail": "Dynamic code...",
        "referenceId": "Dynamic code...",
        "locale": "Dynamic code..."
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the trustpilot documentation,

> The structured data snippet needs to be included in the source code of
> the transactional email that you’re using to trigger AFS.
>
> It’s very important to note that the snippet must be implemented with
> the dynamic placeholders used by your specific platform.

It is suggested to add the snippet to the source code of the email. So you can use WooCommerce email hooks to add the snippet.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_trustpilot_snippet', 20, 2 ); 
function add_trustpilot_snippet( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {  
    ?>
        <script type="application/json+trustpilot">
        { 
        "recipientEmail": "<?php echo $order->billing_email; ?>", 
        "recipientName": "<?php echo $order->billing_first_name.' '. $order->billing_last_name; ?>", 
        "referenceId": "<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>",
        }
        </script>
}
```

This will give you an idea about how to implement the feature. Make use of `$sent_to_admin` variable if you need to target admin emails.

For more WooCommerce email hooks, refer the below link
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/